# Multichannel distance from a reference sequence

Tags: sequence-analysis, traminer

I am working with a large dataset and applying multichannel sequence analysis to two life course domains. I would like to adapt a solution suggested in the post below to multichannel sequences, but I cannot find a way to adapt TraMineR `seqdist()` so that it works with multichannel sequences. **I am looking for a way to calculate a multichannel distance from a reference sequence**:

```
library(TraMineR)
data(biofam)
b.seq <- seqdef(biofam[, 10:25])

## compute pairwise distances on a random subset
spl <- sample(nrow(b.seq),400)
bs.seq <- b.seq[spl,]
d.lcs <- seqdist(bs.seq, method="LCS", full.matrix=FALSE)

## cluster the random subset
bs.hclust <- hclust(as.dist(d.lcs), method="ward.D")
#plot(bs.hclust, labels=FALSE)
cl <- cutree(bs.hclust,k=4)

## plot clusters for random subset
seqdplot(bs.seq, group=cl, border=NA)

## Medoids of the clusters
c.cl <- disscenter(d.lcs, group=cl, medoids="first")
seqiplot(bs.seq[c.cl,]) # plot of the medoids

## distances to each medoids
dc <- matrix(0,nrow=nrow(b.seq),ncol=length(c.cl))
for (i in 1:length(c.cl)) {
  dc[,i] <- seqdist(b.seq,method="LCS",refseq=spl[c.cl[i]])
}

## cluster membership for the full sequence dataset
##  is for each row the column with the smallest distance
cl.all <- max.col(-dc) 

## now we can plot clusters for the whole dataset
seqdplot(b.seq, group=cl.all, border=NA)
```

This example code is taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62888071/too-many-unique-sequences/63037549#63037549).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using function `seqMD` with argument `what="MDseq"` you get the multidomain/multichannel sequences, i.e., the sequences of the combined states of the different domains.
Once you have these multidomain sequences, you can compute any distance available with `seqdist` and, of course, use the `refseq`argument to compute distances to a reference sequence.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(biofam)

## Building one channel per type of event left home, married, and child
cases <- 200
bf <- as.matrix(biofam[1:cases, 10:25])
left <- bf==1 | bf==3 | bf==5 | bf==6
married <- bf == 2 | bf== 3 | bf==6
children <-  bf==4 | bf==5 | bf==6

## Building sequence objects
left.seq <- seqdef(left)
marr.seq <- seqdef(married)
child.seq <- seqdef(children)
channels <- list(LeftHome=left.seq, Marr=marr.seq, Child=child.seq)

## Building MD sequences
MD.seq <- seqMD(channels, what="MDseq")
## Distances from MD sequences to a reference sequence
MD.diss <- seqdist(MD.seq, method="HAM", refseq=MD.seq[1,])
```

Comment: Thank you, it did solve my issue. Thanks again.